# Vector. How to set the maximum number of elements and find the current count?

Tags: c++

I want to create a vector with a maximum number of elements 48, and I want to know at any time the current number of elements in the vector.

I use this code:

**.h**

```
std::vector< CPPobject* >vec;
```

**.mm**

```
int maxCountElementInVec = 48; 
vec.resize( maxCountElementInVec );
int countElement  = sizeof( vec ) / sizeof( vec[0] );

printf("%d ",countElement); // return 3
```

<...>

```
vec.push_back( some_cpp_obj );
int countElement  = sizeof( vec ) / sizeof( vec[0] );
if( countElement > maxCountElementInVec ) printf("Evrika"); 
printf("%d ",countElement); // return 3
```

CountElement always is 3

Answer (score 7):

Finding the number of elements can be achieved with the `.size()` method.

For setting a limit, you can create a wrapper over `std::vector`:

```
template<typename T>
class MyVector : public std::vector<T>
{
    int _maxSize;
public:
    void setMaxSize(int maxSize) {_maxSize = maxSize;}
    void push_back(const T& element)
    {
        if (std::vector<T>::size() < _maxSize)
           std::vector<T>::push_back(element);
        else
        {
           //disallow - throw exception or whatever
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This can leak if MyVector is upcast to a std::vector.  Change your inheritance to private, though (and expose as much std::vector interface as you desire) and this won't leak.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot set the maximum number of elements.

The length however is retrieved with

```
int length = myVector.size();
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrapper Not Good. That open the door for memory leak because std::vector have no virtual destructor.

Let leak some memory:

```
// Construct std::vector & MyVector
std::vector * v = dynamic_cast<std::vector *>( new MyVector() ); 
// Destruct only std::vector
delete v;
```

That's construction of MyVector without a call to it's Destructor.

Let go crazy:

```
MyVector * mv = new MyVector(); // Construct std::vector & MyVector

std::vector * v = dynamic_cast<std::vector *>( mv );
delete v; // Destruct only std::vector

mv.resize(74); // Usage of a partially destroy object.
```

That's use a partially destroy object. Let's spin the wheel of trouble!

Comment: True, but does not answer OP's question.  Private inheritance or even plain-vanilla encapsulation can be used to wrap std::vector without risk of leaking.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the number of elements in the vector is very simple. Just call `vec.size()`. You can not restrict the vector not to resize over the reserved size.

What you query is the size of the structure of vector over the size of a simple pointer. The elements of the vector are not part of this size - thus you get constant size.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `sizeof` on STL vectors is doing something very useful here. As pointed out by Kerrek in a comment, it does not evaluate to something that is proportional to the number of elements in the vector. Just use `size()` to get the current number of elements held in the vector.

You could switch to EASTL, which provides `fixed_vector` which is just like a vector except all memory is allocated up-front, so it can't grow to more than what you specify. It still maintains a `size()` tracking how many elements have been inserted, though.

Comment: Of course `sizeof` is well defined. It gives you the size of the vector object, which is unrelated to the size of the memory that is *managed* by the vector object.